# Giving Focus to Upper Div and Disable Focus on Lower Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, blackberry-webworks

I wondering if it's possible to give focus to upper div and at the same time disable focus on the lower div?

I have this Blackberry app that allow user to reject claims. When user clicks on the Blackberry menu key to select reject to reject a claim, it will require the user to key in remarks. The interface for user to key in remarks will be a div on top on the existing div.

Is there anyway to place focus on the upper div and disable focus on the bottom div until user as click on a button to close the upper div?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this to bring the focus to the upper div and at the same time disable focus on the lower div:

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#upperDivID').offset().top }, 'slow');
```

and if you want to do the vice-versa:

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#lowerDivID').offset().top }, 'slow');
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/b4uQJ/)